# problem on dihedral group

Tags: group-theory

[image]

i have done 1st and 2nd part. i dont know how to proceed for 3rd part, any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Which part do you have problem with?

Comment: First, every element of $\overline{H}$ has order 2, and $|\overline{H}|=4$ (check). This shows $\overline{H}$ is isomorphic to the Klein 4-group. Next, $\overline{H}$ has index 2 in $\overline{G}$, which shows that it is normal. Finally, if you write out the elements of the cosets, you'll find the preimage of $\overline{H}$ pretty fast (hint: it's $\langle t,s^2\rangle$)